# Macro that I created in MS Access VBA cant be activated with .bat file

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've created a macro in Access VBA that sends tasklist emails to all the staff in our division. I would like to schedule this macro to run every monday. So far, it seems that I need to create a .bat file that runs this macro, then I use task scheduler to run this batch file every Monday. The macro I've created is called ScheduleEmails.
[image]

The macro works, I can run it from the VBA window.

The batch file Ive created has the following text:
**"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\Users\42253\Documents\RealEstate\RealEstate_ActionList_V6.accdb" /x ScheduleEmails**
[image]

When I run this .bat file I get the following error:
[image]

I've added the folder that this is happening into the trusted list and the database content is enabled. What am I doing wrong?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I apologize if this has been answered already, but I can't find anything that has worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter /x calls an Access Macro, not a VBA routine.

You need to create a Macro in Access, name it for example `StartScheduleEmails` and have a command `RunCode`. Note that you need to add the parenthesis to the call, else it will not work.

[image]

This will execute a *Function*, not a Sub, so you will need to change the type of `ScheduleEmails` to `Public Function ScheduleEmails()`

Comment: I have done this, then I get an error stating "The expression you entered has a function name that Microsoft Access can't find"

Comment: I changed the module name and function name as they were the same, this has resolved the problem. Thank you so much!